# Reattach shell session to process running on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform

I have an ongoing process running on a GCP vm. When initially start the program it spits our logs in real-time from the shell session, however when I exit the session and re-connect the next day the logs are gone.

How do I reconnect to the process to see the logs again in real-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the program **screen**

This might be already installed, check with:

```
screen --version
```

If not, install with one of these commands (OS specific)

```
yum install screen
apt install screen
```

Open a screen session

```
screen
```

Run your program. You can now disconnect your SSH session. Later you can reconnect using SSH and resume the running **screen** session:

```
screen -r
```

[Screen User Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html)